# JavaScript this refers to window instead of object inside function

Tags: javascript, this

I get confused on a JavaScript `this` reference situation.

I am working on a code that I declare function inside an object method. (The reason is to tidy up code inside an object method, while keeping the functions private to the method.)

The following is an experiment to re-produce my problem.

I found that the `this` inside `greeting` function refers to the *window* scope instead of *person* scope.

```
var person = {
    nickname: "Makzan",
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log(this);
        var greeting = function() {
            console.log(this);
            return "Aloha " + this.nickname;
        }
        console.log(greeting());
    }
}
person.sayHi();
```

(same code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/makzan/z5Zmm/)

And this is the log result in browser:

```
> Object
> Window
Aloha undefined
```

In JS, I know that *this* reference is tricky. And I can change the scope by using `.call` method to make this code works.

```
var greeting = (function() {
    console.log(this);
    return "Aloha " + this.nickname;
}).call(this);
```

However, I am curious to know why by default the `this` refer to *window* scope inside the *greeting* method?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: It is because `greeting` is called without a context.

Comment: Thanks all. I learn more on what 'context' means now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this` has nothing to do with *scope*. It is determined by *context*.

`greeting()` calls the function with no context, so `this` is the default object (`window` in a browser).

Answer (score 4):

The `this`, references is not related to scope, it depends on the calling context.

As per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this),

> In general, the object bound to this in the current scope is
>   determined by how the current function was called

Answer (score 2):

Try person.nickname, this refers to the var greeting in your case

Answer (score 0):

If we modify your code a little, we can see that this works:

```js
var person = {
  nickname: "Makzan",
  greeting: function () {return "Aloha " + this.nickname;},
  sayHi: function () {return console.log(this.greeting());}
}

person.sayHi();
```

So we may conclude the reason that this doesn't:

```js
var person = {
    nickname: "Makzan",
    sayHi: function () {var greeting = function () {return "Aloha " + this.nickname}; console.log(greeting()); }
};

person.sayHi();
```

is because for `greeting()` to have the `this` context of the `person` object, it must be *explicitly* declared as a direct property of the `person` object.