# this. references Object instead of Window-Object

Tags: javascript, reference, this, window-object

I have an Object like shown below.

On line 6 I write `console.log(this.title, elem)`.

Now according to what I learned about ***this.***-Keyword, `this.title` shouldn't reference the current Object here, but the global Window-Object. Now contrary to my knowlede, `this.title` seems to correctly reference the property of the video-Object.

```
const video = {
    title: "a",
    tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    showTags() {
        this.tags.forEach(elem => {
            console.log(this.title + ": ", elem)
        });
    }
}
video.showTags();
```

This is what the Browser shows:

```
a:  a
a:  b
a:  c
```

I thought, that since `console.log(this.title, elem)` is inside a callBack-Function, a reference to the Global Window-Object would be made. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831509/javascript-this-refers-to-window-instead-of-object-inside-function) confirms my notion that `this.title` should actually reference the Global Object.

Could somebody explain?

Comment: `showTags` is a member of that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context. Since you are using `Arrow` function here, the value of `this` inside the forEach() method points to the lexical environment in which it is declared. That is inside the `showTags()` method, so it has same `this` value as that of `showTags()`.

If arrow function was not used here, then the value of `this` would be window, as in the snippet below:

```js
const video = {
    title: "a",
    tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    showTags() {
        this.tags.forEach(function(elem ) {
            console.log(this.title, elem)
        });
    }
}
video.showTags();
```

Comment: I just tried it and indeed... the `arrow`-function makes all the difference. I always thought that arrow-Notation was just a matter of syntax-refinement. Thank you!

Comment: @Josh You can mark an answer accepted by the checkmark to help others finding better answers.

Comment: I didn't realize that I was allowed to do that as a rookie-poster. Is just did now.